# Anchor with height: 100% is larger than parent div (on mobile browsers)

Tags: html, css

I created a simple grid with grid-items.
Some grid-items (divs) should be clickable, therefore I added an anchor tag inside the grid-items.

The anchor should be as large as the parent div, so I set *height* and *width* properties of the anchor to *100%*.

It works perfectly fine and as expected on Desktop browsers (see code snippet). But on mobile browsers [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8olc.jpg).

On mobile the below code snippet also shows this effect, so [here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHJR3.png) of how it looks on desktop.

Why is the anchor larger than the parent div?
How can I avoid this?

Strangely enough it only affects *height*, but not *width*.

Thank you :)

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.grid-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.grid-item > a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: lightsalmon;
    color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <title>Random Website Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><a href=#>LINK</a></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself, it was actually fairly simple.

While defining the grid, I only defined the grid columns (grid-template-columns). After also defining the grid rows (grid-template-rows) the issue went away. I also learned that I can combine columns and rows with the `grid-area` property.

So in the end I just replaced the line `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);` with `grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr)`

Here is the updated code snippet:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.grid-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid black; 
}

.grid-item > a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: lightsalmon;
    color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <title>Random Website Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><a id="a" href=#>LINK</a></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="style.js"></script>>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `.grid-item > a` class replace:

```
height: 100%;
```

with:

```
height: calc(100% - 4px);
```

Because you have inner borders of 2px from top and 2px from bottom

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it didn't fix the issue. Using your suggestion makes the height smaller than the parent div.
But I was able to find a solution myself, see my answer.